# javascript: Find repeated (adjacent & non-adjacent) chars in a string

Tags: javascript, indexof

I'm trying to find a repeated character in a string and have it working, but there is an issue when I input an adjacent char. My function ends up outputting the first sequential repeated char.  Any idea why my first condition is not executing? Expected output should be "C", but I end up with "B"

```js
    function findFirstRepeatedChar(s){
      for(let i=0; i<s.length; i++){
        if(s[i] == s[i+1]){
          return s[i];
        }else if(s.indexOf(s[i], i+1) != -1){
          return s[i];
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
    console.log(findFirstRepeatedChar("ABCCBD"));
    //console.log(findFirstRepeatedChar("ABCDB"));
    //console.log(findFirstRepeatedChar("ABCDE"));
```

Comment: You're not at the stage for asking this on SO yet - you can discover what is wrong entirely on your own by adding `console.log(s[i], s[i+1])` in a few places and seeing what your code actually does, given that you only feed it  a 6 character string. Just put some console logs in your function (e.g. before and inside the if blocks) and see what its input/extracted values are at each step, and then look back at your code run and see whether what it logs and what you thought it did match up or not.

Comment: because b is the first character according to your else if.....

Comment: The issue I'm having is that the function is supposed to output the first repeated char in a linear way. I have the if statement to check for adjacent chars and the elseif to check for non-adjacent chars. in this case, both statements eval to true, but the 2nd statement is executed instead of the first... which is what is currently stumping me.

Comment: If you want to search first for adjacent matches, and then at any distance, you need two for loops. As it is currently written, you get B because it is first duplicated character. Else is executed for i = 1 too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning on first sequential match result and not first adjacent. Storing non adjacent matches and returning them at the end of function moves the propriety to the return the first adjacent match.

```
function findFirstRepeatedChar(s){ 
    var ot = false;
    for(let i=0; i<s.length; i++){

      if(s[i] == s[i+1])  { 
         return s[i];
       }   else if(s.indexOf(s[i], i+1) != -1){
         ot = s[i]; 
       }
     }

       return ot; 

} 
console.log(findFirstRepeatedChar("ABCCBD"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have put return into for and then you get only one value.
If you create an array and put in it the duplicate elements,after you can display the elements array.

Try this code and get BC for string(ABCCBD) B(ABCDB) and nothing (ABCDE)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <script>
    function findFirstRepeatedChar(s){
      var arr=[];
        
      for(let i=0; i<s.length-1; i++){
         if(s[i] == s[i+1] && (i+1<=s.length)){
             //return s[i];
             arr.push(s[i]);
         }else if(s.indexOf(s[i], i+1) != -1 && (i+1<=s.length)){
                 //return s[i];
                 arr.push(s[i]);
               }
      }
                  
           for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        
              console.log(arr[i]);
        
           }
        return false;
    }
       console.log(findFirstRepeatedChar("ABCCBD"));
       //console.log(findFirstRepeatedChar("ABCDB"));
       //console.log(findFirstRepeatedChar("ABCDE"));
   </script>
 </head>
<body>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps